# How to distinguish zero from very small number in floating-form

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I am about to develop a scientific calculator. My question is:
How can I distinguish zero result from very small numbers using float number?

For example, for 0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1, the result is something like 1E-19, which is not pure zero (precision problem, of course). I want to print out the result (0.0). So I use the EPSILON to do the comparison with zero.

The problem is, for the calculation: 3E-19 - 2E-19 the result should be 1E-19. I should print out the exactly result (though small) 1E-19. But if I still use the EPSILON comparison, the result is forced to be zero.

So, again, my question is: How can I do the check for zero and very small numbers?

Comment: Is using floating-point arithmetic a strict requirement in your project, or would you be willing to consider alternative arithmetic implementations?

Comment: I would consider string manipulation or using a library like GMP.

Answer (score 5):

This is inherently not possible if you use binary floating point datatype.

Instead, if you want precise control over numeric precision and rounding, you should use a decimal number library, for example [GNU Multiprecision (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think I should try using GMP. I have not used it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You said that 0.3-0.2-0.1 is not 0 but rather 1E-19. Actually it's already float(0.3)-float(0.2)-float(0.1) which is no longer 0. Unless you explicit check if 0.3 could be encoded in float or double losslessly then there is no way you can check if the small number you get after the calculation is due to operand error or really a small number.

Answer (score 0):

In case you've not come across it [this page](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) is basically the last word in floating point comparison.

However I think your problem comes down to knowing what precision is needed based on the operands and on the operations that have been performed. You may be able to judge that from the biggest ULP between operands. If there's a large ULP between the operands then you might need to display a more precise answer (up to to limit of precision available in floating please representations). May be worth experimenting with something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the scientific calculator will run into this issue with equations like `1.0 - 7*(1.0/7.0)` *regardless* if code uses `double` (binary FP) or high precision libraries of base 2, 10.

**Use a decimal floating point library** to *minimize* the occurrence of round-off error issues with decimal inputs like `0.1, 0.2, 0.3`.

"I want to print out the result (0.0). So I use the EPSILON to do the comparison with zero." fails as FP numbers have a logarithmic distribution.

Consideration: Allow the **user to control the format** of the *displayed* output.  In essence this allows the user to set EPSILON.  E.g. `"%.17f"` and `0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1` will come up zero.

Comment: "Allow the user to control the format" results in the fact that the user can still find out the calculator is 'poor in accuracy'. T.T

Comment: @guan boshen The "poor" accuracy results from using floating point (in any base) to covert a number (text "0.1") into a not-exactly representable internal number such as `double`.  That is the source of the issue.  Depending on the coding goals, there are various solutions - some certainly easier/more portable than others.  Even if code uses a base-10 floating point, the same problem occurs given that 1) text input precision can exceed internal representation and 2) some results are not finite representable `1.0/7.0`.  User can __still__ find out the calculator is 'poor in accuracy'

Comment: Yes, do you know much about GMP? By GMP, can I specify the exact number of 'significance digits'? For example, 1.23456789E-19 has 9 significance digits.

Comment: @guan boshen I only have modest experience with GMP.